# Use the response from shell inside yml for Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to install MongoDB via Ansible playbook, I am following the instruction in:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16.04/

For the step about "Step 2 - Create source list file MongoDB"

I should use:

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

while it get the ubuntu version with the following command:

```
$(lsb_release -sc)
```

How can I do it via yml file and run it via ansible palybook?
I used the below yml command but it is not working and gives me error since I use shell command "$(lsb_release -sc)" inside my script

```
- name: Create source list file MongoDB
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: >
    line="deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"
    dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
    state=present
    create=yes
```

Comment: using `lineinfile` is always a red flag, you can and should easily do this with `template`. Also, you can use `{{ansible_distribution_release|lower }}` instead of lsb_release.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can register the result of one task, including its stdout, as a variable then use it in later tasks:

```
- name: Work out the distribution
  command: lsb_release -sc
  register: result

- name: Create source list file MongoDB
  sudo: yes
  lineinfile: >
    line="deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu {{ result.stdout }}/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"
    dest=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
    state=present
    create=yes
```

Comment: I am new to yml and never knew this option, thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. You'll also find this is an ansible feature, not a yaml feature.

Answer (score 13):

There is [apt_repository](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/apt_repository_module.html) module in Ansible:

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu {{ ansible_distribution_release | lower }}/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse
    state: present
```